# Python Urllib2 Use Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I am using the following code to use a Proxy in urllib2

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '198.154.114.100'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

How can I check whether the proxy is really used? I want to print the IP used for the urllib module.

Answer (score 0):

One indirect way is to use sites such as ifconfig.me which provide IP information:

```
opener.open('http://ifconfig.me/ip').read()
```

would read the IP provided by the above service.